# Some problems understanding pseudo code

Tags: pseudocode

I'm facing some problems for my assignment recently Can any expert tell me what is meant by set tiles={} in the following pseudo code?

This is what I have:

```
Greedy-String-Tiling(sToken,tToken)   
{   
  tiles={};   
  do  
  {   
    searchLength=MinML;   
    matches={};   

    ForallunmarkedtokenssTokensinsToken   
    {   
      ForallunmarkedtokensintTokensintToken   
      {   
        j=0;   
        while(sToken+j==tToken+j&&unmarked(sToken+j)&&unmarked(tToken+j))   
        j++;   

        if(j==searchLength)   
          [B]matches=matches?match(s,t,j);[/B]      
        elseif(j>searchLength)   
        {   
          [B]matches={match(s,t,j)};[/B]   
          searchLength=j;   
        }   
      }   
    }   
    Forallmatch(s,t,searchLength)?matches   
    {   
      Forj=0...(searchLength 1)   
      {   
        mark(sFiles+j);   
        mark(tFilet+j);   
      }   

      tiles=tiles?match(s,t,searchLength);   
    }   
  }while(searchLength>MinML);   

  returntiles;   
}
```

I hope to know what is meant by `tiles={}` and `matches={}`.

Comment: I tagged this as 'homework' as you did say it was an assignment. If that is not the case, please remove the tag.

Comment: I removed 'vba' tag and added 'pseudocode' as well

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code Should be easy to read and understand. This could hardly be called *pseudocode*, though it is intended as such. Anyhow, `tiles={}` and `matches={}` are `sets` or `arrays` here.